Consuming a .zip file from asp.net core controller in an ajax call results in invalid zip file
I have searched stack overflow and the web for a few days and have seen many examples of creating a zip file on the server in an asp.net controller and sending the response to an ajax call on the client, but everything I try results in an invalid zip file when opening the downloaded data.
The ajax call posts data for what the zip should contain.  The server grabs images from an Http call to a content management system and then zips the images into a zip file. in js, I set the returned data to a blob and then place it in a window.URL.createObjectURL. It then sets the download of an anchor in a popup asking the user to click the anchor to download the zip file. I have verified that the zip data is valid from the server by writing it to disk and opening the zip.
Here is the ajax call:
$.ajax({
url: downloadUrl,
type: 'post',
data: "searchText=".concat(modelData).concat("&source=").concat(target.id),
}).done(function (data, status, xhr) {
var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
var blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: contentType
});

//set blob to anchor
var aDownload = document.getElementById('download-file');
aDownload.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
aDownload.download = "downloadfile.zip"

//Popup 
document.getElementById("embed-popup").hidden = true;
const embedCode = document.getElementById('embed-popup');
embedCode.value = target.dataset.embed;
document.body.classList.add('show-embed');
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    autosize.update(embedCode);
});

});
Here is the server Controller:
[HttpPost]
public async Task ResourcesDownload(ResourceSearch resourceSearch)
{
ResourceSearchResult resourceResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resourceSearch.SearchText);
    string[] resourceSearchSplits = resourceSearch.Source.Split('|');
    SubCategory subCategory = resourceResult.SubCategories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == resourceSearchSplits.Last());

    using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (Resource resource in subCategory.Resources)
            {
                string fileSuffix = resource.FileType.Split('/')[1];

                string title = Regex.Replace(resource.Title, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", String.Empty);
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.CreateEntry($"{title}.{fileSuffix}");

                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(resource.FileUrl)))
                    {
                        using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            await stream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        zipStream.Position = 0;

        // Generate the HTTP response with the zip file
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(zipStream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "downloadfile.zip"
        };

        return File(zipStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "downloadfile.zip"); 

}
Clicking the link starts the ajax call and sends the resource info of what the zip should include:
(https://i.sstatic.net/lQm5ec89.png)
Server then returns the zip data and the popup us displayed to the user.  When user clicks link it downloads the file:
(https://i.sstatic.net/iVmUiCCj.png)

You should let the File return to the browser directly.  (Just make a standard form post.)  Creating an objectURL just makes a copy which is inefficient.

Thanks for the reply.  The process can take some time to complete so there is a message stating retrieving download...  I thought having the popup was a nice way for them to know that the zip is ready to download.

For large files, there are also some limits for client-side storage so beware there as well.  I would check/debug the value of "contentType"... xhr headers may return something more generic.

Did you try setting the $.Ajax xhrFields response type to blob?  (See this answer

With the form post, is there a way to know when the browser has, started and finished the downloading of the file? I could then tell the user that the download is complete.

Not without some silly client-side mojo... (target an iframe, polling it... I think you need a cookie too if I remember right... it's easier with uploads as you can just poll the iframe for existence of the response)  The browsers are pretty good at showing progress though.

James, I looked at that post and did that. The data then says the blob = "[object blob]" and has a size of 13 which is that text.  If I do not include the blob in responsetype I get back what looks like binary data.

Side notes: using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) is a bad idea, it'll end up opening new sockets again and again. Instead use a static client or IHttpClientFactory. Your HttpResponseMessage is being ignored as you don't do anything with it, either return it and don't use File( or remove it.

Charlieface, thanks for the info.  I will implement those changes.

I was able to get this to work using an Xmlhttp request instead of the ajax call. From this post: Prompt file download with XMLHttpRequest.
Works with my original popup after zip has been returned in the response.  User is prompted to click the link to save to the downloads folder.
const resourceListClick = e => {

let target = e.target;

if (target.classList.contains('download-link') || target.classList.contains('video-link')) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var downloadUrl = document.getElementById('download-url').innerText;

    var modelData = JSON.stringify(retrievedResourceData); 

    var postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('searchText', modelData);
    postData.append('source', target.id);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', downloadUrl, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var blob = e.currentTarget.response;
        var contentDispo = e.currentTarget.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        
        var fileName = contentDispo.match(/filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/)[1];
       
        var aDownload = document.getElementById('download-file');
        aDownload.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        aDownload.download = fileName;
        aDownload.innerText = fileName;

        document.getElementById("embed-popup").hidden = true;

        const embedCode = document.getElementById('embed-popup');
        embedCode.value = target.dataset.embed;
        document.body.classList.add('show-embed');
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            autosize.update(embedCode);
        });

    }
    xhr.send(postData);
}

}
